# Unable to read e-mails from Outlook for last 1 hour with Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to read emails from my outlook for last 1 hour. I have used the below code. here i am not getting any error but it is not giving me any output.

```py
import win32com.client
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

date_time = dt.datetime.now()

lastHourDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(minutes=60)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
message = messages.GetLast()
lastHourMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastHourDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p') + "'")
timeStamp = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S")

for lastHourMessage in lastHourMessages:
   print(lastHourMessage.subject)
```

I checked the `len(messages)`, it is giving me total count of inbox mails. Whereas `len(lastHourMessages)` is showing as 0.

According to me, `Restrict` function is not working properly. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Change `%y` to `%Y` at line below.

```py
lastHourMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastHourDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p') + "'")
```

---

Just to be sure, correct is

```py
lastHourMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastHourDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p') + "'")
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

I added some debug info in your code to help understand what going wrong.
Try to use code below. Hope, it will help you.

```py
import win32com.client
import datetime as dt

one_hour_before = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(minutes=60)
print(f'one_hour_before: {one_hour_before.astimezone()}')

# Get Outlook NameSpace object.
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Get The Inbox folder.
# Other folder types:
#   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders
inbox_folder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
print(f'{inbox_folder}\n')

# Get collection of Outlook items and sort.
messages = inbox_folder.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

# Check all items and ReceivedTime.
for it, message in enumerate(messages):
  print(f'{it}\t{message.ReceivedTime} - {message.Subject}')

  # If recevied one hour before, print it.
  received_time = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(message.ReceivedTime.timestamp())
  if received_time >= one_hour_before:
    print(f'^^^\tRECEIVED ONE HOUR BEFORE')

# Get items received one hour before, if there are.
one_hour_before_messages = \
  messages.Restrict( "[ReceivedTime] >= '"
                   + one_hour_before.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
                   + "'")

# Print them
if len(one_hour_before_messages) == 0:
  print('No items received one hour before.')
else:
  print('Items received one hour before:')
  for one_hour_before_message in one_hour_before_messages:
    print(f'{one_hour_before_message.ReceivedTime} \
- {one_hour_before_message.Subject}')
```

Result of code above:

```sh
one_hour_before: 2020-03-09 12:31:06.515809+09:00
受信トレイ

0       2020-03-09 13:19:04.102000+00:00 - RE: TEST
^^^     RECEIVED ONE HOUR BEFORE
1       2020-03-09 09:46:10.128000+00:00 - TEST
Items received one hour before:
2020-03-09 13:19:04.102000+00:00 - RE: TEST
```

Comment: ..I changed the same. But still i am not getting the desired output.

Comment: Can you provide one more time exact code what you use? Cuz in current question’s code you had some misspellings.

Comment: i have edited my code as suggested by you. .. You can check it.. I am running the same code.

Comment: Tou again use %y, but you must use %Y.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209154/discussion-between-panda-and-yeheshuah).